# XSLT: Move child node after parent node

Tags: html, xml, xslt, parent

I'm currently using XSLT to clean and alter some (exported) HTML. Works pretty good so far. ;)

But I need to alter a table so that the tfoot will be copied outside the table.

Input: (exported by Adobe Indesign):

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Stuff</td>
        <td>More Stuff</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td>Some footer things</td>
        <td>Even more footer</td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Stuff</td>
        <td>More Stuff</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

My expected output:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Stuff</td>
        <td>More Stuff</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Stuff</td>
        <td>More Stuff</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div class="footer">
    Some footer things
    Even more footer
</div>
```

The first thing I do in my XSL is to copy everything:

```
<xsl:template match="*|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

But what's the next step? Is this even possible with XSLT? Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you just edit the HTML after exporting? also `tfoot` is not the same as  `div.footer`

Comment: This was just a very simplified example. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="table">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="thead"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="tbody"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="tfoot"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tfoot">
    <div class="footer">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="tr/td/text()"/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am not sure how exactly you want to arrange the contents of the footer `div`; you might want to use `xsl:for-each` to insert a separator between the text nodes.

Note also that the result here is not well-formed XML, because it has no single root element.

Comment: Thank you, this helped my a lot.

The "real" markup is much more complicated, I just simplified it for my question.